# Statistical test to compare predictive measures with count data

Tags: predictive-models, count-data, validation, pearson-r

I'm reviewing a paper that compares predictors of healthcare demand in terms of hospital visits for several conditions. The authors have used a Pearson's rho to determine which is best, and further compare estimates using % error in predicted versus real values.

For reasons I cannot quite articulate, I don't think this is the best approach; e.g., since Pearson's rho treats the data as ranked, it will have trouble with extreme values. I also suspect there are much more sensitive and sophisticated methods than a simple correlation. The authors also state that highly correlated and significant results indicate the validity of the predictors.

Can anyone describe:

1. Whether there are better methods for comparing predictive measures.
2. If a Spearman correlation is not the best approach, why?
3. Can this approach be used for validation?

Excuse me for outsourcing peer review; I take the role seriously and want to give the best feedback!

Comment: This isn’t a statistics-based response, but you’re enough of an expert in your field to review a paper, and you don’t get why they’re using this technique. The authors didn’t explain it well! A totally fair comment to write in your review is that they should expand on why they chose the methodology. Others (hopefully) will read this paper if it gets published, and they’re likely to have the same question.

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair point. My feedback was going to ask for clarification as well as the explanation and citations for the approach were lacking.